# Why can't I connect to mysql with command line but can do that with DataGrip?

Tags: mysql

I got a username and password from others and has connected to that MySQL database for days with DataGrip. Today I used mysql command line to connect that database but I got an access denied error. I used the same command line to connect other database and it worked rather than this database.

I am curious that why DataGrip can connect to the database with username and password while command line can't. I've tried for tens of time so there should not be typo. PyMySQL and official Java connector can connect while offical C/C++ connector can't do that with that database. What is the setting that makes this happen?

The command line I use:

```
mysql -h 10.224.23.21 -u board -p
```

And the password is typed correctly.

The error message is

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'board'@'10.227.24.176:39300' (using password: Yes)
```

Comment: what mesage do you get?

Comment: @nbk Error message has been added.

Comment: i think that you shoud check the grants, and see if board can access from the computer ip

Comment: @nbk I have checked that and board can access from all the IP starts with 10. And the DataGrip runs on the same computer with the command line. So, it maybe has some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue was caused by the new version connector tried to connect the old version of MySQL server. MySQL 8.0 uses caching_sha2_password as default. So if I want to connect the old version of MySQL, I need to change the plugin to mysql_native_password.